# problems installing tensor flow on MacOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am having problems installing tensorflow on Mac. My MacOS is High Sierra 10.13.3. I have python 2.7, pip 9.0.1. I have typed the following:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
pip install tensorflow.
```

And the error I get is the following. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Installing collected packages: mock, enum34, backports.weakref, numpy, wheel, absl-py, protobuf, futures, html5lib, bleach, werkzeug, markdown, tensorflow-tensorboard, tensorflow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock'
```

`Permission denied` mostly means you need to retry with `sudo`

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```